# nodejs/js: Only first function of async.series is executed even after calling back

Tags: javascript, node.js

Only first function of async.series is executed, the second one doesn't even start for the below code:

```
var async = require("async");
var src = 0;
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        callback("Called from 1");
    },
    function(callback){
        callback("Called from 2"); 
    }]
, function (desc) {
           console.log(desc)
           src++           
           console.log(src+".1."+"--->"+src)
           console.log(src+".2."+"now it should return")            
        }
    );
```

Any idea why this is not reaching the second one?

The output:

```
Called from 1
1.1.--->1
1.2.now it should return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe the first argument for callback should be null callback(null,"called from 1")

Comment: Thanks Fadi for pointers - I have also elaborated further below.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Fadi.
Just to elaborate, the callback here goes with a mandatory signature of **err,desc,.....other args**.
As observed, whenever I passed a not-null or not-false value in the first param, the execution stopped there and then - didn't execute next function in series i.e. stopped at the first true error received.

Also, I had assumed that the callback will be called after each series function is executed but it's actually called after all functions in series are executed.

Rectified as below:

```
var async = require("async");
var src = 0;
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null,"Called from 1");
    },
    function(callback){
        callback(false,"Called from 2"); 
    }]
, function (err,desc) {
           console.log(desc)
           src++           
           console.log(src+".1."+"--->"+src)
           console.log(src+".2."+"now it should return")            
        }
    );
```

Output:

```
[ 'Called from 1', 'Called from 2' ]
1.1.--->1
1.2.now it should return
```

Comment: @King Reload: Yes but the answer needed more elaboration - I wanted to provided more information to other people who would have come and would have gone through the solution. Thanks for down vote anyways. Also, that is what I have accepted as an answer.

Comment: I got rid of the downvote, but please consider editing someone else's answer instead if they haven't provided enough information! :) thanks

Comment: @KingReload: i considered that and then that's precisely what i didn't want to do. I wanted to maintain the sanctity of Fadi's short answer for users who would understand it in a single look while ones needing more info can go down to take a look at the  detailed solution. I guess just a difference of viewpoints.

Comment: I agree in your decision, excuse me for my rudeness!

Comment: @KingReload no problems - "rudeness is better than untruth!" - myself

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in your callback functions should be null, like this:

`callback(null, "Called from 1");`

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series